# xlwt write: Unexpected data type <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>

Tags: python, python-3.x, xlrd, xlwt

I have again problem with writing values in excel workbook. I figured out how to use both xlrd + xlwt for my purpose, but since I changed code for converting datetime values and exceptions with uncoded strings it doesn't work anymore.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\rs_al\IdeaProjects\ExcelToSQL\PyXLSSQL\XLS_xlutils.py", line 96, in <module>
    Excel.xls_wrk(filename)
  File "D:\rs_al\IdeaProjects\ExcelToSQL\PyXLSSQL\XLS_xlutils.py", line 89, in xls_wrk
    ws.write(row_idx,col_idx, val)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Worksheet.py", line 1088, in write
    self.row(r).write(c, label, style)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Row.py", line 254, in write
    raise Exception("Unexpected data type %r" % type(label))
Exception: Unexpected data type <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'>
```

I've checked all cell types, there are only type 1 unicode string, type 2 float and type 3 float.
When I print values everything is ok.

Code:

```
import ftfy
import xlrd
import xlwt
from xlrd import open_workbook




class Excel:
    #convertin to xlsx for working with openpyxl
    def xls_wrk (filename):
        #XLRD
        rb = open_workbook('abbcards.xls')
        rs = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
        rows = rs.nrows
        cols = rs.ncols
        wb = xlwt.Workbook()
        ws = wb.add_sheet('Part1')

        #iterate and prepare format for SQL db tables
        for row_idx in range (0,rows):
            for col_idx in range (0,cols):
                cell= rs.cell(row_idx, col_idx)
                ctp_in = cell.ctype
                cval = cell.value



                #Input string value "whitespace" in empty cells
                if (ctp_in == xlrd.XL_CELL_EMPTY):
                    ctp_in = xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                    cval = " "
                elif (ctp_in == xlrd.XL_CELL_ERROR):
                    ctp_in = xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                    cval=" "

                #Fixing date
                elif (ctp_in == xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE):

                    #Manual fixing negative value
                    if (cval==-693594):
                        ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE
                        cval = rs.cell(row_idx, col_idx-7)
                    else:
                        ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_DATE

                        cval=xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(cval, rb.datemode)

                #fixing negative values

                elif (ctp_in == xlrd.XL_CELL_NUMBER and cval < 0):
                    cval= 0

                #Fixinig broking UTF-8 as 1252 letters with package ftfy

                elif (ctp_in == xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT):

                    #Broken UTF-8 that ftfy package can't fix. Manual fix

                    #CarPlate from "abbcardds"
                    if(cval=="Ð 869Ð¡Ð—197"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval = "Р869СЗ197"
                    elif (cval=="H613Ð'Y"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval="H613BY" #important. Car plate number is in Latin
                    elif (cval=="Ð'509Ð¡Ð'777"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval="В509СВ177"
                    elif (cval=="Ð'674Ð¡Ð¡199"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval="В674СС199"
                    elif (cval=="T357KÐž777"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval = "T357KО777"
                    elif (cval =="Ð'010Ð¡Ð¡199"):
                        #=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval="В010СС199"
                    elif (cval=="E174Ð¡Ð 777"):
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval = "E174СР777"
                    else:
                        #ctp_in=xlrd.XL_CELL_TEXT
                        cval=ftfy.fix_text(cval)
                #print(cval)

                ws.write(row_idx,col_idx, cval)
          wb.save('text.xls')
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't quite match your code - note the use of `val` vs `cval`.

Comment: I would put a `print(row_idx, col_idx, cval)` just before, and that should tell you which of the three is of type `xlrd.sheet.Cell` and not the value you expected it to be.

Comment: @asongtoruin I can't understand your comment. What difference between cval and val?

Comment: @Torxed I printed it, types were only 1 Unicode string, 2 float, 3 float. What about converted datetime? Could it be possible that excel datetime format  and not python format raises exception?

Comment: @Torxed I printed it, types were only 1 Unicode string, 2 float, 3 float. What about converted datetime? Could it be possible that excel datetime format  and not python format raises exception?

Comment: @RostislavAleev your error code references a line consisting of `ws.write(row_idx,col_idx, val)`. This line isn't found in the script you have provided, where instead you use `ws.write(row_idx,col_idx, cval)`. Are you sure the error and your script actually match up?

Comment: @asongtoruin oh, ty. It's a copy-paste issue.

Comment: 1. xlwt convert dates into excel format so `cval=xlrd.xldate.xldate_as_datetime(cval, rb.datemode)` is useless. It converts everything btw.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that if you do `print(type(cval))` it's not a unicode string, that's just a representation of the object?

Comment: @Torxed, well, found it `3 11 xldate:text:'V' <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'> 3`

Comment: How it can be possible? ` xldate:text:'V' (XF:70) (XF:65) <class 'xlrd.sheet.Cell'> 3` 2 types for a string

Answer (score 0):

Solved

1. print(row_idx, col_idx,cell,type(cell.value),cell.ctype)
   as said **Torxed**
2. check class, because mine was cell class. Instead of putting only value `cval = rs.cell(row_idx, col_idx-7)` I took cell().